# how to implement pager in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pager

how to implement data pager in asp.net C# like below image?

[image]

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of Cutome paging and than you can do it there are no of example available on google for this ....

here is one for you : http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=55#

Comment: This link is dead now :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you use MVC, but when I did I used this tool:
http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2008/08/27/paging-with-aspnet-mvc/
It worked out very good for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LINQ to achive paging:

[paging example](http://solidcoding.blogspot.com/2007/11/paging-with-linq.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PagingInfo
{
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }        
    public int TotalPages
    {
        get { return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems / ItemsPerPage); }
    }
    public int TotalDisplayPages { get; set; }
}
```

and then use this class in pagingHelper metioned below..

```
public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,PagingInfo pagingInfo,Func<int,string>pageUrl)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        var start = pagingInfo.CurrentPage > 1 ? pagingInfo.CurrentPage - 1:pagingInfo.CurrentPage;
        var end = start + pagingInfo.TotalDisplayPages;
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            var tag = new TagBuilder("a");                
            // Construct an <a> tag
            tag.MergeAttribute("href", "");

            tag.InnerHtml = (i).ToString();
            if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                tag.AddCssClass("selected");
            result.AppendLine(tag.ToString());
        }
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can select set of rows by row number 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133
and by getting the whole row count you can determine how many pages you'll need 
after that not much programming JS C# and CSS you'll have even better than the image

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply
I need something like
                
<<first <prev  [1] [2] [3] Next > Last >>
<<first <prev  [4] [5] [6] Next > Last >>

what you have redirect me is like 
<<first <prev  [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] Next > Last >>

I just want to show only 3 buttons in Paging...

Comment: My friend its just "switch case" scenario, if Pages >3 show only the current page number and 2 more numbers, i used this approach i a website and its working perfectly!!

Comment: i'm not able to do that..:( could you post a code for that? thx

Comment: sql :
select rank() OVER (ORDER BY a.au_lname, a.au_fname) as rank,name
   from student where rank <10 and rank >5 /* depend on the current page */                    
____________________________________
asp/C# in a fast way (i'll check it when i get home)...
if (currentPage==1)
startPageNumber=1;
if (curentPage==LastPageNumber)
startPage=LastPageNumber-2;
if (LastPageNumber<3)
startPageNumber=1;
for(int i=startPageNumber;i<=startPageNumber+2;i++){
//create label/link button 
}

//just check that we haf covered all cases sir,